# Python "\n" не работают в строке, которая возвращается из БД

Tags: python, строки

Храню в базе данных MongoDB разные строки, например: `"Abc \n Abc"`, когда пытаюсь её вывести через print(my_string), то получаю вывод: `"Abc \n Abc"`, вместо ожидаемого:

```
"Abc 
Abc"
```

Вот сам код:

```
my_string = get_one_string_from_bd()
print(my_string)
print(type(my_string))
print(repr(my_string))
```

Вывод:

```
Abc \n Abc
<class 'str'>
Abc \\n Abc
```

Что я делаю не так и как заставить работать перевод строки?
Проблема решается если добавить (n с двумя палочками, заменить на n с одной палочкой, почему-то на этом сайте заменяется на 1) .replace("\n", "\n") к строке, но это как-то странно.

Comment: Смотрите 2 параметр конструкции `print`.

Comment: print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False), вы имеете ввиду sep?

Comment: да, задайте перевод. через `end`.

Comment: Хотя, странно, должно работать, сейчас попробовал, там же по умолчанию перевод стоит. Может всеже строка приходит какой-то другой? Странно строка `print('Abc \n Abc')` работает как нужно. Хм, ну попробовать стоит `print('Abc \n Abc', end='\n')` И гляньте реально ли в базе лежит `\n`, а то мало-ли он как-то конвертнулся. Попробуйте прям с базы в `end=''` вставить и проверить.

Comment: Если я вставлю строку в таком виде, в котором вставили вы: print('Abc \n Abc') или print('Abc \n Abc'), то у меня тоже все будет отлично работать, проблема когда я пытаюсь сделать это с строкой полученной из БД.

Comment: print(my_string)
print(type\n my_string))
print(repr\n my_string))
Имеете ввиду это?

Comment: попробуйте сравнить рабочий вывод и ваш из бд через ==, может там строка с другими по коду элемента символами?

Comment: Покажите, как Вы добавляете и получаете эту строку из БД.

Comment: А у вас точно именно после такого replace всё начинает работать? Может быть, у вас там всё-таки replace(r"\n", "\n") или replace("\\n", "\n") ?

Comment: Ничего странного в этом нет. Строка из БД не содержит символа перевода строки, в ней есть последовательность символов ``\`` и `n`. Строка, скорее всего, была преобразована в JS с помощью `JSON.stringify`. Думаю, вам подойдёт `my_string = my_string.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`

Comment: И ещё `import codecs` а потом `codecs.escape_decode(my_string)[0].decode('unicode-escape')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка из БД не содержит символа перевода строки, в ней есть последовательность символов `\` и `n`. Строка, скорее всего, была преобразована в JS с помощью `JSON.stringify`.

Для того, чтобы восстановить пробельные символы в строке, можно использовать

```
my_string = my_string.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

И ещё

```
import codecs
my_string = codecs.escape_decode(my_string)[0].decode('unicode-escape')
```

[Пример работы кода в Python 3](https://rextester.com/XGN94434)

Comment: Если в строках только `r"\n"` встречается, то можно просто `my_string = my_string.replace(r"\n", "\n")` делать.

Comment: @insolor Да, можно использовать и такое. Просто если был использован метод вроде JSON.stringify, лучше воспользоваться чем-то более универсальным.